# How can i allow people in my local network to access the web service in my machine?

Tags: web-services, apache-axis, jboss5.x, windows-firewall, local-network

I have coded a web service using the Axis 2 framework and I can successfully invoke it using a test client (SoapUI) on the local machine after publishing the application in JBoss 5.  I can post to the WS endpoint from the local machine and get the expected response.

Now i want to allow other machines to access the web service.

i changed the "localhost" to "my own fixed IP" adress at the end point location, and turned firewall off, but impossible to access the WS.

Note : windows Xp SP3.

Any idea ?
Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Is there an error message?  Do the clients see that machine at all?  (That is, can they ping it?  Can they telnet to the service's port on it?)  Are they not able to access it at all, or is it throwing an error from the server when they try?  (Meaning that they _can_ access it but it's just broken in some way.)  We need information in order to determine what the problem might be.

Comment: While running the JBOSS, have you bind the jboss services to ur IP.By using run -b command?

Comment: thank u for yr comments! Actually, they can ping my machine, but impossible to connect with telnet command like "telnet 1.2.3.4 8080". When i changed "localhost" to "my IP adress" at the endpoint location, i got the message : ACCESS DENIED !! @Murugesh : yes i tried with the -b option in eclipse.

Comment: Are you able to access the application's URL from other machine's browser.You are getting the ACCESS DENIED ! message only when you trying to access the EndPoint address from the Web Services clinet ?

Comment: thank u Murugesh. Actually, now i can access application url from other machines through browser and by using SOAPUI. All what i did is a) changing my application runtime configuration from JBOSS V5.0 to JBOSS AS 5.1 b) adding argument -b 0.0.0.0, in Eclipse. Now All is fine !! thanks all of U.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure you follow below steps

For example, if your ip is 10.132.243.54

- List item
- Checking if your IP is pingable by other systems
- Instead of running with eclipse, run your jboss from your
  command-prompt
- start jboss-server suffixing -b in run.bat. The command is **run.bat
  -b 10.132.243.54**
- Access the WS from SOAP-UI using IP and not using localhost
- If your IP is still not pingable, turn off the firewall, after
  following above steps

Sorry for the late reply, However this would solve the problem i guess